# Amazon EC2 :- Not able to downgrade PHP version from 7.4 to 7.2

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to downgrade `PHP` version from `7.4` to `7.2`. This is what did

1. `sudo amazon-linux-extras | grep php` and it shows `PHP 7.4` as the enabled version.

[image]

2. Disable PHP 7.4 `sudo amazon-linux-extras disable php7.4`
3. Enable PHP 7.2 `sudo amazon-linux-extras enable php7.2`
4. Installing related modules `sudo yum install php php-{pear,cgi,common,curl,mbstring,gd,mysqlnd,gettext,bcmath,json,xml,fpm,intl,zip,imap}`
5. Checking the enabled version again `sudo amazon-linux-extras | grep php`
   [image]

Now it shows `7.2` as the enabled version.

6. Restarting httpd `systemctl restart httpd.service`

After this when I check `php -v` it still shows `7.4`
[image]

Can anyone point out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalling worked for me.

1. Uninstall PHP   `yum -y remove php*`
2. Reinstall PHP and related modules   `sudo yum install php php-{pear,cgi,common,curl,mbstring,gd,mysqlnd,gettext,bcmath,json,xml,fpm,intl,zip,imap}`

Answer (score 0):

Probably your php path variable is not pointed correctly.
Please do check the path variable in your centOS configuration once again.

Comment: Thanks @Miracle. I tried reinstalling php and that works.